# Is it possible to represent Sufficient Condition relation in OWL?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

Related questions [Necessary and sufficient conditions for inferring a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902946/owl-reasoning-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-inferring-a-property), [Representing if-then sentence using OW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496364/representing-if-then-sentence-using-owl)

Base on my understanding of `owl:equivelantClass`  and `rdfs:subClassOf` we can represent `Necessary Condition` and `Necessary and Sufficient Condition` using *subClassOf* relation (one directional subClassOf or bi-direction subClassOf which is *equivalentClass*).

If we want to represent condition **N** is `Necessary Condition` of **S** (*IF S THEN N*), we can model this in following:

```
S rdf:type owl:Class;
  rdfs:subClassOf [
  rdf:type rdf:Restriction;
  owl:onProperty :N;
  owl:hasValue :D
  ].
```

or just say:

```
S rdfs:subClassOf N.
```

If we want to represent condition **N** is `Necessary and Sufficient Condition` of **S** (*N IIF S*), we can model this in following:

```
N rdf:type owl:Class;
  owl:equivalentClass [
  rdf:type rdf:Restriction;
  owl:onProperty :S;
  owl:hasValue :D
  ].
```

or just say:

```
N owl:equivalentClass S.
```

My question is can we represent `sufficient condition` using OWL? I'm thinking maybe I can represent the `Sufficient Condition` by reverse the order of *Restriction Class* and *A*.

### Edit

According to the definition of [Necessary and Sufficient condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency), the assertion of `N is Necessary for S` is equivalent to `S is Sufficient to N`, we can understand this as `N is super-set of S` or `S is subset of N`.

Base on the accepted answer, we can model this relationship as `S rdfs:subClassOf N` or define a `superClassOf` property:

`:superClassOf owl:inverseOf rdfs:subClassOf`

and assert `N :superClassOf S.`

### Conclusion

So the answer is yes, we can represent Sufficient condition by reverse the order (define a inverse property of *rdfs:subClassOf*) of Necessary condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditions, of course, refers to "conditions on an individual for class membership", and are expressed in terms of defining ever-smaller (more restricted) subclasses of the overall "class of all things".

In that context, a sufficient condition is simply the inverse of a necessary condition. So in effect, every time you specify a necessary condition, you *also* specify a sufficient condition.

Let's spell that out.

A necessary condition on a class `X` is the following: "IF the individual `i` is an instance of the class `X`, THEN the condition must be true". `subClassOf(X, Y)` means that IF an `i` is of class `X`, THEN it must also be of class `Y`, so in other words if we want to say that `i` is in `X`, it's *necessary* that it is also in `Y`. But it's not *sufficient* for `i` to be in `Y` to conclude that it is in `X`.

A necessary *and sufficient* condition on class `X` is a condition where in addition it also holds that "IF the condition is true, THEN the individual must be an instance of the class". In other words "if `i` is in class `Y`, this is sufficient evidence that it is also in `X`". This is the equivalence relation, which specifies that the sets of individuals of two classes are exactly the same (so if `i` is in `Y`, it must be also in `X`, vice versa).

A condition on `X` that is *only* sufficient, but not necessary, would mean that you have some relation `R(X,Y)` for which it holds that IF an indivual is in `Y`, it is also in `X`, but not necessarily that IF it is in `X`, THEN it is also in `Y`. This is the superclass relation, in other words the inverse of the subclass relation.

So when you say `subClassOf(X, Y)` you have not only defined a necessary condition for `X`, but effectively also a sufficient condition for `Y`. After all, if we know an individual `i` is an instance of `X`, then that is *sufficient* to conclude it's also an instance of `Y`. But it's not *necessary* for `i` to be an instance of `X` to also be an instance of `Y`: there can be instances of `Y` that are not in `X`.

In OWL there is no explicit separate `owl:superClassOf` relation. However if you really wanted to express it in those terms, you could conceivably introduce a superClass relation yourself, simply be defining it as the `owl:inverseOf` the subClassOf relation.